# UIAccessibility announcing n of n elements on custom views

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility

When you add a UISegmentedControl to a view, `UIAccessibility` will focus on it and say:

```
"(Selected) ItemName Button 1 of 2"
"ItemName Button 2 of 2"
```

I have a custom control that has `UIButtons` that toggle similar to a `UISegmentedControl`. But what I'm trying to figure out is how to get the Voice Over to announce the `n of n` at the end.

The closest thing that I've found is assigning the `.accessibilityTraits = .tabBar` on the container. The issue is that it announces:

```swift
"ItemName Button Tab 2 of 2"
```

But to conform to our accessibility guidelines we can't have it announce "tab".

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/uiaccessibilitytraits/1648592-tabbar

Short of just writing a custom `accessibilityLabel` is there anything within UIAccessibility that can handle this logic?

Answer (score 2):

1. Set the container view's accessibilityTraits = .tabBar
2. Set the container view's accessibilityElements = [button1, button2]
3. Set each button's accessibilityTraits = .selected or .none when necessary

Answer (score 0):

> I have a custom control that has UIButtons that toggle similar to a UISegmentedControl. But what I'm trying to figure out is how to get the Voice Over to announce the n of n at the end.

- Put each one of your `UIButton` elements in the `accessibilityElements` array of the custom control that acts like a container.
- By searching a specific element in this array, you will have an index 'x' inside a total amount 'N' of buttons: *"item name button x of N"*.
- In your `UIButton`, set `accessibilityLabel` by inserting the result of the previous research.

[image]
Here's a kind of logic that should help you reach your purpose with a little bit of code as follows for instance *(Xcode 10.2.1, Swift 5.0, iOS 12)*:

```
class ButtonsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomContainer: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn3: UIButton!


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        myCustomContainer.accessibilityElements = [btn1!, btn2!, btn3!]
        let nbButtons = myCustomContainer.accessibilityElements?.count

        for (index, elt) in (myCustomContainer.accessibilityElements?.enumerated())! {

            let btn = elt as! UIButton
            let btnName = btn.titleLabel?.text

            btn.accessibilityLabel = btnName! + String(index + 1) + " of " + String(describing: nbButtons!)
        }
    }
}
```